# Отступы ListView в SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

Дело в том что я использую `ListView` внутри `SwipeRefreshLayout`. И `Refresh` срабатывает нормально только, если в `ListView` заданы отступы слева и справа. Как только задаю Сверху или Снизу, то `Refresh` исчезает.

**Разметка:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srl_direction="both">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:listSelector="@color/transparent_color"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Сейчас первый пункт в списке прилипает к `ToolBar`, поэтому нужно задать отступ. С `CardView` пробовал, но тоже не подошел.

Как исправить, подскажите?

Comment: сделайте отступ в разметке айтема, а не самого виджета `ListView`

Comment: Ставте только верхний отступ, а не с обоих сторон.

Comment: попробуйте установить отступы вовнутрь у SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: Ну, расстояния между айтемами и должны быть какие-то , не в плотную же они располагаются. Я обычно ставлю айтему верхний маржин в 8dp и все хорошо смотрится. Соответственно контент айтема верстается с учетом этого маржина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте отступ только первому элементу разметки ListView. В адаптере, в методе `getView` проверьте, что `position==0` и проставьте разметке верхний отступ. Иначе - обычный (нулевой) отступ.

Comment: @Omuradil, посмотрите в конец моего ответа. Там сказано, что кроме if надо ещё и `else` прописать. А в нём 0 поставить.